# What's the correct way to sort Python `import x` and `from x import y` statements?

Tags: python, coding-style, python-import, pep8

The [python style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) suggests to group imports like this:

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. standard library imports
> 2. related third party imports
> 3. local application/library specific imports

However, it does not mention anything how the two different ways of imports should be laid out:

```
from foo import bar
import foo
```

There are multiple ways to sort them (let's assume all those import belong to the same group):

- first `from..import`, then `import`

  ```
  from g import gg
  from x import xx
  import abc
  import def
  import x
  ```
- first `import`, then `from..import`

  ```
  import abc
  import def
  import x
  from g import gg
  from x import xx
  ```
- alphabetic order by module name, ignoring the kind of import

  ```
  import abc
  import def
  from g import gg
  import x
  from xx import xx
  ```

PEP8 does not mention the preferred order for this and the "cleanup imports" features some IDEs have probably just do whatever the developer of that feature preferred.

**I'm looking for another PEP clarifying this or a relevant comment/email from the [BDFL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum)** (or another Python core developer). *Please don't post subjective answers stating your own preference.*

Comment: I doubt there is a "correct" way.  What's wrong with picking your own style on this?  There can hardly be a convention if no one knows it.  And does it really matter?  What is the advantage of having this specified?

Comment: Also see this relevant thread: [Import order coding standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722976/import-order-coding-standard).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Imports are generally sorted alphabetically and described in various places besides PEP 8.

**Alphabetically sorted modules are quicker to read and searchable**. After all, Python is all about readability.
Also, it is easier to verify that something is imported, and avoids duplicate imports.

There is nothing available in PEP 8 regarding sorting. So it's all about choosing what you use.

According to few references from reputable sites and repositories, also popularity, Alphabetical ordering is the way.

for e.g. like this:

```
import httplib
import logging
import random
import StringIO
import time
import unittest
from nova.api import openstack
from nova.auth import users
from nova.endpoint import cloud
```

OR

```
import a_standard
import b_standard

import a_third_party
import b_third_party

from a_soc import f
from a_soc import g
from b_soc import d
```

Reddit official repository also states that In general PEP-8 import ordering should be used. However, there are a few additions which are that for each imported group the order of imports should be:

```
import <package>.<module> style lines in alphabetical order
from <package>.<module> import <symbol> style in alphabetical order
```

References:

- https://code.google.com/p/soc/wiki/PythonStyleGuide
- https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/PythonImportGuidelines
- http://docs.openstack.org/developer/hacking/
- http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/external/plone.api/contribute/conventions.html#grouping-and-sorting

PS: the [isort utility](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isort/) automatically sorts your imports.

Comment: I don't see where you're answering the actual question…

Comment: @liori I submitted a reference/relevant links stating how to sort modules . As PEP 8 don't mention anything but many another references do suggest to use import methods like this.

Comment: Note that the question is about sorting `import x` and `from y import z` statements relative to each other. I see no answer to this question in your answer. You're basically restating part of the question that already explains the PEP8 way of grouping by import type. If an answer to this specific question is in some of the links, please quote the relevant parts.

Comment: What order should be used for private vs public imports? (`import _tkinter` vs `import unittest`)

Answer (score 80):

According to the CIA's internal coding conventions (part of the [WikiLeaks Vault 7 leak](https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/page_26607631.html)), python imports should be grouped into three groups:

1. Standard library imports
2. Third-party imports
3. Application-specific imports

Imports should be ordered lexicographically within these groups, ignoring case:

```
import foo
from foo import bar
from foo.bar import baz
from foo.bar import Quux
from Foob import ar
```

Comment: Upvoted for the laugh factor that it is the CIA's coding style guidelines. Very clever, but at the same time relevant given the level of expertise coming from those developers.

Comment: that's verbatim [google python style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Imports_formatting)

Comment: Updated link: [Google Python Style Guide - Section 3.13: Imports formatting](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#313-imports-formatting).

Comment: But it does not follow from the example if `from x import y` should be before or after `from y import x` - is it the name of the module or the actual import which determines the order?

Comment: I know it's a joke, but as a proper nerd I want to point out that this is actually coming from PEP8

Comment: where would this import go?  
`from foo.abc.def import ghi`

Comment: ok, but within each group, should the "import"s come before the "from"s ? For example is this order correct ? "import json", "from io import StringIO" and "import pandas as pd" ?

Answer (score 12):

The PEP 8 says nothing about it indeed. There's no convention for this point, and it doesn't mean the Python community need to define one absolutely. A choice can be better for a project but the worst for another... It's a question of preferences for this, since each solutions has pro and cons. But if you want to follow conventions, you have to respect the principal order you quoted:

1. standard library imports
2. related third party imports
3. local application/library specific imports

For example, [Google recommend in this page](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Imports_formatting#Imports_formatting) that *import should be sorted lexicographically*, in each categories (standard/third parties/yours). But at Facebook, Yahoo and whatever, it's maybe another convention...

Comment: To answer the question more directly, the Google style guides recommend sorting by the path, which is the third option from the question: "alphabetic order by module name, ignoring the kind of import"

Answer (score 10):

I feel like the accepted answer is a bit too verbose. Here is TLDR:

> Within each grouping, imports should be sorted lexicographically,
>   ignoring case, according to each module’s full package path

[Google code style guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#313-imports-formatting)

So, the third option is correct:

```
import abc
import def
from g import yy  # changed gg->yy for illustrative purposes
import x
from xx import xx
```

Comment: Worth noting this isn't an official rule from the maintainers of python, this is just one particular style guide

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend [reorder-python-imports](https://pypi.org/project/reorder-python-imports/). It follows the 2nd option of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20763446/1354930) and also integrates into [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/), which is super helpful.

Comment: I recommend `isort`. Unfortunately `reorder-python-imports` treats anything symbolic linked as third party.

Answer (score 2):

All `import x` statements should be sorted by the value of `x` and all `from x import y` statements should be sorted by the value of `x` in alphabetical order and the sorted groups of `from x import y` statements must follow the sorted group of `import x` statements.

```
import abc
import def
import x
from g import gg
from x import xx
from z import a
```