# Import order coding standard

Tags: python, python-import, static-analysis, pep8

[PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id16) suggests that:

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> 1. standard library imports
> 2. related third party imports
> 3. local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

Is there a way to check if the standard is violated anywhere in the package using static code analysis tools, like `pylint`, `pyflakes`, `pychecker`, `pep8`?

---

Example of violation:

```
from my_package import my_module
from django.db import models
import os
```

Correct way to import:

```
import os

from django.db import models

from my_package import my_module
```

Comment: The `pep8` tool doesn't currently check this - it only checks for multiple imports on one line (E401)

Comment: [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) might do this but I'm not 100% sure. It costs moneys though.

Comment: @Claudiu turned on all python inspections - it doesn't find the problem in the import order. Thanks.

Comment: @Claudiu - Pycharm has a community version too.

Comment: If you don't end up finding something, you could write your own pylint plugin to check this for you. Take a look at [pylint-plugin-utils](https://github.com/landscapeio/pylint-plugin-utils) and an example plugin [here](https://github.com/landscapeio/pylint-celery). (This might be better suited as a comment but I don't have the reputation to comment.)

Comment: [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (free) can fully optimize and sort your imports: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html  You can even configure how the sorting happens under Settings | Editor | Code Style | Python | Imports

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The current version of pylint now does this, and reports it as error class C0411.

Comment: This should be a higher-voted answer now. For more recent versions which don't display the error numbers anymore, it's error class `wrong-import-order`.

Answer (score 56):

Update (2016): [sbywater](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213338/771848) has the most recent answer.

---

Found it! (accidentally, while reading "Hacker's guide to python")

*OpenStack Hacking Style Checks* project named [hacking](https://github.com/openstack-dev/hacking) introduces several unique [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) extensions. There is [hacking_import_groups](https://github.com/openstack-dev/hacking/blob/master/hacking/checks/imports.py) among them (related [commit](https://github.com/openstack-dev/hacking/commit/b321905608b63c3d8a0f0ea7921c72c479b4f938)).

Example:

- requirements

  - [tox](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
  - [flake8](https://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
  - [hacking](https://github.com/openstack-dev/hacking/) (from the master branch):

    ```
    $ git clone https://github.com/openstack-dev/hacking.git
    $ cd hacking/
    $ python setup.py install
    ```
- files used in the example

  - `tox.ini` (we need to tell flake8 that we want to use a custom check)

    ```
    [hacking]
    local-check = hacking.core.hacking_import_groups
    ```

    UPD: with the newest version of `hacking` the path to the check changed, now it is `hacking.checks.imports.hacking_import_groups`.
  - `test.py` (target of the check)

    ```
    import requests
    import sys
    from my_module import print_smth


    print_smth(requests.get('https://google.com'))
    print_smth(sys.version)
    ```
  - `my_module.py` (local import used by `test.py`)

    ```
    def print_smth(smth):
        print smth
    ```

Then, if I run `flake8` against `test.py`:

```
$ flake8 test.py
test.py:2:1: H305  imports not grouped correctly (requests: third-party, sys: stdlib)
test.py:3:1: H305  imports not grouped correctly (sys: stdlib, my_module.print_smth: project)
test.py:3:1: H306  imports not in alphabetical order (sys, my_module.print_smth)
```

Then, if I group the imports in the correct order following `PEP8`:

```
import sys

import requests

from my_module import print_smth


print_smth(requests.get('https://google.com'))
print_smth(sys.version)
```

No warnings found:

```
$ flake8 test.py
$
```

Hope this will help somebody in the future.

Comment: They took out this check, citing that it was too error-prone and difficult: https://github.com/openstack-dev/hacking/commit/8f1fcbdb9aa4fc61349e5e879153c722195b1233#diff-d941f383e7dafcdea3d0ff128d92b497L500

Answer (score 31):

Have a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isort or https://github.com/timothycrosley/isort

> isort parses specified files for global level import lines (imports outside of try / excepts blocks, functions, etc..) and puts them all at the top of the file grouped together by the type of import:

> - Future
> - Python Standard Library
> - Third Party
> - Current Python Project
> - Explicitly Local (. before import, as in: from . import x)

> Custom Separate Sections (Defined by forced_separate list in configuration file)
> Inside of each section the imports are sorted alphabetically. isort automatically removes duplicate python imports, and wraps long from imports to the specified line length (defaults to 80).

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-isort plugs this functionality into flake8

Edit (2023) [Ruff](https://docs.astral.sh/ruff/) can also check or sort the imports according to this standard.

Comment: Just note that if you run `isort script_name.py --check-only` - it would only check for unsorted imports and print out the results - this is what I needed. Thank you very much for the option.

Comment: `isort -rc --check --diff` check all files recursively, only checking, display a diff

Answer (score 7):

A `flake8` plugin exists: [flake8-import-order](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8-import-order).

> This package adds 3 new flake8 warnings
>
> I100: Your import statements are in the wrong order.
>
> I101: The names in your from import are in the wrong order.
>
> I201: Missing newline between sections or imports.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly, You need to structure your import statements to meet [pep8 import standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

I found [isort](https://pypi.org/project/isort/) library useful in ordering import statements to get rid of flake8 ordering issues.

```
pip install isort
isort <your_python_file>.py
```

Answer (score 1):

The Flake8 plugin Alphabetize https://github.com/tlocke/flake8-alphabetize checks import sort order and is designed to work with the Black formatter. It follows the Black formatter approach of having a single style, with no configuration of the style possible. Alphabetize also checks the order of the `__all__` attribute.