# Pyhon module import order relevance, pylint wrong-import-order

Tags: python, import, pylint

Recently I started using pylint to check my python code.

I was surprised to see the following messages:

```
C: 18, 0: standard import "import anydbm" should be placed before "import numpy as np" (wrong-import-order)
C: 19, 0: standard import "import pickle" should be placed before "import numpy as np" (wrong-import-order)
```

All the imports are at the top of the script anyway.

Why would it matter in which order I import these modules?

I didn't notice that any of my code was broken when the import order was not optimal (according to pylint). Until now, I have assumed that all modules are independent, but maybe I'm wrong...

In the meantime, I have found this information: [Import order coding standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722976/import-order-coding-standard), which seems to confirm my assumption/observation.

Can someone please confirm, that these modules are indeed not related and the import order is relevant only for the cosmetic purpose?

Comment: The import order is not irrelevant, it's specified in PEP8. Whether it impacts functionality is irrelevant to whether it contradicts the official style guide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to sort Python \`import x\` and \`from x import y\` statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762662/whats-the-correct-way-to-sort-python-import-x-and-from-x-import-y-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import order doesn't affect the functionality of your program. But there is a style guide that suggests how you should order them. The wrong-import-order warning just means you didn't follow that.

But this was already asked and answered elswhere:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26804809/660389