# Pylint complains when importing in the right order

Tags: python, pylint

I thought the correct order of imports in Python was the one described by the first answer of the question: *[What's the correct way to sort Python `import x` and `from x import y` statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762662/whats-the-correct-way-to-sort-python-import-x-and-from-x-import-y-statement)*

Therefore, this code should be correct:

```
import os
import time
import yaml

from collections import OrderedDict
from xtesting.core import testcase
```

However, when I run Pylint I get:

```
C:  5, 0: standard import "from collections import OrderedDict" should be placed before "import yaml" (wrong-import-order)
```

So I guess "yaml" is not a standard library. Should then the correct way to do it be this one (even if it is uglier and less readable)?

```
import os
import time
from collections import OrderedDict
import yaml

from xtesting.core import testcase
```

Comment: `yaml `doesn't come by default and Pep is a suggestion, use whatever you think is more aligned with your code-base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyYAML is not part of the standard Python library and imports from the standard library, whether generic (`import os`) or specific (`from collections import OrderedDict`) should come first.

You should, IMO, lexicographically sort on the module names in the sections and separate the sections with an empty line:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import os
import time

from xtesting.core import testcase
import yaml
```

There are some that want the generic ones to all come first, in each section:

```
import os
import time
from collections import OrderedDict

import yaml
from xtesting.core import testcase
```

This looks nicer, but it makes it easier to overlook specific imports after a long generic lists. And it also separates a generic and specific import from one and the same module, which, IMO, is bad:

```
import yaml
from xtesting.core import testcase
from yaml import safe_load
```